# How to choose multiple columns from a sympy matrix? Broken indexing?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, indexing, sympy

I'm trying to pick multiple columns from a sympy matrix. However, the indexing does not work as expected. The code

```
import sympy as sp

stdA = sp.Matrix(
  [
    [-2, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1]
  ]
)

b = sp.Matrix(
  [
    [3],
    [2]
  ]
)

B1 = stdA[:, [0, 1]]
B2 = stdA[:, [0, 2]]
B3 = stdA[:, [0, 3]]
B4 = stdA[:, [1, 2]]
B5 = stdA[:, [1, 3]]
B6 = stdA[:, [2, 3]]

print("std A =", stdA)
print("b =", b)

print("B1 =", B1)
print("B2 =", B2)
print("B3 =", B3)
print("B4 =", B4)
print("B5 =", B5)
print("B6 =", B6)
```

prints

[image: Output of a Python script]

See the issue with `B3`, and the matrices after it? It' supposed to read `B3 = Matrix([[-2, 1], [0, 1]])`. I thought slicing Sympy matrices produces copies of them, so `stdA` shouldn't be altered in place.

What is causing this erraneous behaviour, and how can I choose specific columns from a matrix with simple indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requested all rows and columns 0 and 3. That is what you got:

```
>>> B3
Matrix([
[-2, 0],
[ 1, 1]])
```

Matrix presents the contents as a list of rows.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was hell bent on  getting a list of columns for some reason.